# create table syntax in joomla2.5 programming under the joomla-database

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_employee` ( `employee_id` int(10) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `email_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL, `contact_number` int(20) NOT NULL, `address` varchar(300) NOT NULL, `date_of_birth` date NOT NULL, `nationality` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL, `date_of_joining` date NOT NULL, `employee_group_id` int(10) NOT NULL, `cast` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `religion` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `marital_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `nominee_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `father_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `mother_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`), KEY `employee_group_id` (`employee_group_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
$db->setQuery($query);
```

It produce error

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error,
>   unexpected 'TABLE' (T_STRING) in
>   C:\wamp\www\joomla\components\com_lmeinstaler\views\lmeinstaler\tmpl\default.php
>   on line 7

can any one inform me where is the error?

Comment: you are trying to load results but you have selected anything in your query as you are trying to create a table. so, are you trying to create a table and add data to it, or are you trying to get data and display it?

Comment: i want to create a table but it display error..

Comment: what is the joomla2.5 syntax for creating table?

Comment: Best place to create tables is using the sql file during extension installation: `install.mysql.utf8.sql`: [Developing a Model-View-Controller Component/2.5/Using the database](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Using_the_database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following to create a table:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__employee` ( `employee_id` int(10) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `email_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL, `contact_number` int(20) NOT NULL, `address` varchar(300) NOT NULL, `date_of_birth` date NOT NULL, `nationality` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL, `date_of_joining` date NOT NULL, `employee_group_id` int(10) NOT NULL, `cast` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `religion` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `marital_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `nominee_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `father_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, `mother_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`), KEY `employee_group_id` (`employee_group_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Few minor tweaks made, the main one being adding the database prefix